# how to use `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1And8bithow` in bc-java or jdk8?

Tags: java, cryptography

I have used this encryption method in Android and there is no problem
But I will report an error when I transplant it to jdk
How to solve the problem?
I tried bc-java but I did not run.

my code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1And8bit");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and jdk8 error:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1And8bit SecretKeyFactory not available
```

Comment: Did you see this article:https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/12/changes-to-secretkeyfactory-api-in.html ? It all has to do with the encoding of the encoding of the input to the PBKDF2 function. When getting the passphrase from the user you need to decode it 'utf-8' and feed it to the PBKDF2 instantiated with "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1".

Comment: Horrid design decision. Yes, the code of Java did for security reasons just use 8 bit, but changing the implementation on Android breaks compatibility. That means that Android is not Java anymore for this particular class, as the use of 8 bits of the character is explicitly defined in Java. They should have created a different name, e.g. `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1AndUTF8` instead. Now you have to use `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1` in Java and `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1And8bit` on Android as Michael has indicated.